# redis - acquiring connection time with PHP clients

Tags: java, php, redis

My use case is a bunch of isolated calls that at some point interact with redis.

The problem is I'm seeing a super long wait time for acquiring a connection, having tried both [predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis) and [credis](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/credis) on my LAN environment. Over 1-3 client threads, the time it takes for my PHP scripts to connect to redis and select a database ranges from **18ms** to **700ms**!

Normally, I'd use a connection pool or cache a connection and use it across all my threads, but I don't think this can be done in PHP over different scripts.

Is there anything I can do to speed this up?

Comment: maybe this is caused by the network problem, ping the redis server ip to test it .

Comment: There's no network problems. Do you have a similar use case and you're not seeing any of my issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Predis needs the `persistent` flag set: https://github.com/nrk/predis/wiki/Connection-Parameters) and also FPM, which was frustrating to set up on both Windows and Linux, not to mention testing before switching to FPM on our live setup.

I've switched to Phpredis (https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis), which is a PHP module/extension, and all is good now. The connection times have dropped dramatically using `$redis->pconnect()` and are consistent across multiple scripts/threads.

Caveat: it IS a little different from Predis in terms of error handling (it fails when instantiating the object, not when running the first call, it returns `false` instead of `null` for nonexistent values - ???), so watch out for that if switching from Predis.